# Mail configuration error in weblogic for SOA

Tags: validation, security, weblogic, soa, email

While configuring gmail setting in em console i am getting below error.

1. I have done smtp, imap certificates for demotrust.jks and demoidentity.
2. I have done settings in emconsole.

[image: images of My email settings]

3. And I configured workflow properties also.
4. While testing i am getting Below error

   ```
   javax.mail.MessagingException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
     nested exception is:
       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:571)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:183)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:132)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.EmailResourceAdapter.createEmailStore(EmailResourceAdapter.java:1290)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.getInitializedEmailStore(MailboxPollingWorker.java:104)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.run(MailboxPollingWorker.java:47)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.runIt(WorkImpl.java:108)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:44)
       at weblogic.connector.work.WorkRequest.run(WorkRequest.java:95)
       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
   Caused By: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1731)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:785)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
       at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:97)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:96)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:61)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:135)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:261)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:114)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:538)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:183)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:132)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.EmailResourceAdapter.createEmailStore(EmailResourceAdapter.java:1290)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.getInitializedEmailStore(MailboxPollingWorker.java:104)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.run(MailboxPollingWorker.java:47)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.runIt(WorkImpl.java:108)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:44)
       at weblogic.connector.work.WorkRequest.run(WorkRequest.java:95)
       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
   Caused By: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:323)
       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:785)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
       at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:97)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:96)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:61)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:135)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:261)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:114)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:538)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:183)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:132)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.EmailResourceAdapter.createEmailStore(EmailResourceAdapter.java:1290)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.getInitializedEmailStore(MailboxPollingWorker.java:104)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.run(MailboxPollingWorker.java:47)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.runIt(WorkImpl.java:108)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:44)
       at weblogic.connector.work.WorkRequest.run(WorkRequest.java:95)
       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
   Caused By: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:217)
       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:925)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:785)
       at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
       at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:97)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:96)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:61)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:135)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:261)
       at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:114)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
       at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:538)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:183)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.ImapEmailStore.initStore(ImapEmailStore.java:132)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.EmailResourceAdapter.createEmailStore(EmailResourceAdapter.java:1290)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.getInitializedEmailStore(MailboxPollingWorker.java:104)
       at oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.MailboxPollingWorker.run(MailboxPollingWorker.java:47)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.runIt(WorkImpl.java:108)
       at weblogic.connector.security.layer.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:44)
       at weblogic.connector.work.WorkRequest.run(WorkRequest.java:95)
       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
   ```

Any help is appeciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to indented your code sample by 4+4 spaces (additional 4 because it is under an ordered list), so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. I also trimmed phrases like "Thanks" as they are not encouraged in SO, however kind they are. Please edit your question to provide any additional information in order to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Exception:

"Caused By: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

is fired because the java process couldn't find the required certificate. Make sure that you imported the certificate to the right truststore and that the start parameter Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore is pointing to that truststore